# Apache .htaccess integration with CommandBox

Tags: commandbox

I am using the latest version of CommandBox and I'm getting errors when I include my existing .htaccess file in server.json located in the webroot of my site. My .htaccess file is also located in the webroot.

I have tried including the .htaccess in the server.json file. It's being included Ok however when I output server log I am seeing errors and after reading the documentation I can't see any reference to including these modules.

Here is the output of the server log command issued from within CommandBox

[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: Include licenses.conf
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: Options All -StopOnError
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule authz_host_module     modules/mod_authz_host.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule auth_basic_module     modules/mod_auth_basic.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule auth_digest_module   modules/mod_auth_digest.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule authn_dbd_module     modules/mod_authn_dbd.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule authn_file_module    modules/mod_authn_file.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule authn_anon_module    modules/mod_authn_anon.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule authz_user_module    modules/mod_authz_user.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule asis_module      modules/mod_asis.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule cache_module          modules/mod_cache.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule dbd_module       modules/mod_dbd.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule dbd_exec_module  modules/mod_dbd_exec.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule deflate_module   modules/mod_deflate.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule dir_module       modules/mod_dir.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule disk_cache_module     modules/mod_mem_cache.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule developer_module      modules/mod_developer.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule env_module           modules/mod_env.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule expires_module       modules/mod_expires.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule filter_module     modules/mod_filter.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule gzip_module           modules/mod_gzip.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule headers_module       modules/mod_headers.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule hotlink_module   modules/mod_hotlink.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule linkfreeze_module   modules/mod_linkfreeze.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule log_config_module    modules/mod_log_config.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule logio_module     modules/mod_logio.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule mem_cache_module modules/mod_mem_cache.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule mime_module      modules/mod_mime.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule proxy_module         modules/mod_proxy.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule rewrite_module       modules/mod_rewrite.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule replace_module       modules/mod_replace.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule setenvif_module      modules/mod_setenvif.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule speling_module        modules/mod_speling.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule seo_module        modules/mod_seo.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LoadModule xsendfile_module      modules/mod_xsendfile.so
[ERROR] org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.utils.ModRewriteConfLoader: Unknown line: LogLevel debug

I believe the rewrites in the .htaccess will work ok with the Tuckey rewritefilter, however I'm not sure why these errors are occurring and after it hits the error it doesn't process the rewrites.

Comment: FYI I'm running LUCEE and CFML.

Comment: If there's anymore information I can add to this please let me know.